# Rails: Fetch feed entries from certain date with Feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rss, atom-feed, feedjira

How's it going SO'ers?

I've appended a *Recent News* section to the top of Users Dashboard, where it fetches news stories through `Feedjira`, saves the `NewsEntry` to the database (postgres) and then picks three random `NewsEntries` to display in the `Dashboard#index` view.

I've also created a rake task `NewsEntry.update_from_feed(feed_url)` to update the table with new `NewsEntries` scheduled to run once every 24 hours.

My problem, because it's a *Recent News* section I would like to fetch the `NewsEntries` that were published today (or yesterday; this could be a time as well). Eventually I'll add to the rake task to remove old articles and update the feed with newer articles. Right now I am getting an error trying to fetch entries on a certain date:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x00007fcab2910d00>
```

**NewsEntry**

```
class NewsEntry < ApplicationRecord
  def self.update_from_feed(feed_url)
    feed = Feedjira::Feed.fetch_and_parse(feed_url)
    add_entries(feed.entries)
  end

  private

  def self.add_entries(entries)
    today = Date.today
    entries.where("published_at = ?", today) do |entry|
      unless exists? :guid => entry.id
        create!(
          :title         => entry.title,
          :url          => entry.url,
          :published_at => entry.published,
          :guid         => entry.id
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What's the question? An `array` object doesn't have a `where` method, just like the error says.

Comment: @jvillian do you have a solid alternative? Like `select` or something similar